# Ionic V4 - Build Prod "Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail."

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic4

In Ionic v4, when I'm run app bundled in production mode **(ionic cordova build android --prod)**, console says 'Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.' and some things of the app like fonts are unload(I see Roboto Font and not my custom font). Otherwise, when I'm triying to compile without production mode**(ionic cordova build android)**, the app ran without console errors.

My Ionic info:

ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.2.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 7 other plugins)

Does anyone face this problem as well?

Cheers,

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Same issue for me. Looking into changing index.html to reference `cordova.js`, not hashed `cordova.sjhdfksjdhfks.js`

Comment: @KirillGroshkov How did you do that ? I can't modify index.html which is in the apk.

Answer (score 3):

In dev environment the address is cordova.js and the file is found.
In prod the file name gets hashed into something like  cordova.4bdae3fd4f9978d7dcd8.js.

Therefore you need to modify the function findCordovaPath() to

```js
function findCordovaPath () {
  var path = null;
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  var startterm = '/cordova.';
  var term = '/cordova.js';
  for (var n = scripts.length - 1; n > -1; n--) {
    var src = scripts[n].src.replace(/\?.*$/, ''); // Strip any query param CB-6007).
    var idx = src.indexOf(startterm);
    if (idx >= 0){
      term = src.substring(idx+1);
    }
    if (src.indexOf(term) === (src.length - term.length)) {
      path = src.substring(0, src.length - term.length) + '/';
      break;
    }
  }
  return path;
}
```

Comment: Would you please give mroe info on how to use this function?

Comment: @Zahema: I have replaced this function in my Ionic app in www/cordova.js. There are other cordova.js files inside the app, some are automatically generated. Depending on the different platforms you create, you may have to change this function in several places.

Comment: Your solution gave me the error :
`ERROR in cordova.8d2879086e40979e9c2d.js from Terser
Invalid regular expression: /?.*$/: Nothing to repeat [cordova.8d2879086e40979e9c2d.js:1932,37]
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.`

Comment: @Kari The regular expression excepted seems to be `var src = scripts[n].src.replace(/\?.*$/, '');`. Why is yours different ? (OS different ?)

Comment: @Marco I just checked again and yes, it should actually contain the backslash before the question mark, making sure it is escaped. Will change my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

temporary fixed with `angular.json` configuration by setting `"optimization": false` and `"outputHashing": "none"`:

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          ...
          "optimization": false,
          "outputHashing": "none",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          ...
        },
        ...
      }
```

Comment: Above workaround works but since optimization is set to false output apk size will be higher(i.e actual size of the apk without optimization).

Comment: This will disable optimization of the build output. Including minification of scripts and styles, tree-shaking, dead-code elimination, inlining of critical CSS, and fonts inlining.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I migrated from ionic 3 to ionic 4. It disappeard after I started a freshly new project (with tabs default) and copied the code.

There seems someone to have found a solution:

> I no longer have that problem. In angular.json, I set buildOptimizer
>   and AoT to false, then I was able to build with --prod. When I
>   reactivated AoT, I see the problem in the log. The dependency
>   injection was doing the wrong way during the migration.
>   Source: [Github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/issues/668#issuecomment-564222348)